# Best way to include forked and unpublished version of a Hackage-published library in my own project

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I am building a project in Haskell using `stack`, and needed to update one of the libraries on which my project depends--let's call that `otherlib`.

I've forked `otherlib` and made the required changes, incremented the version number (let's call my version 0.9.1), built it using `cabal` (which is what that project uses), and run `cabal install otherlib` to put my modified version into the local cache. Now I'd like to include it in my own project as reasonably as possible.

The changes I've made to `otherlib` are (IMO) pretty reasonable and stand a chance of being accepted by the maintainer once I create a PR. But in the meantime, I have a version which isn't in `stack`'s solution set.

Including `otherlib-0.9.1` in my `package.yaml` dependencies doesn't work, nor does adding it to my `stack.yaml`'s `extra-deps`.

Is there a good way of setting this up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify Git repositories (and its revision) in `extra-deps` of stack.yaml.

Here's an example from [the document](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/yaml_configuration/#git-and-mercurial-repos):

```
extra-deps:
- git: git@github.com:yesodweb/wai
  commit: 2f8a8e1b771829f4a8a77c0111352ce45a14c30f
  subdirs:
  - auto-update
  - wai
```

Note `subdirs` is only required when the repository contains several packages (like yesodweb).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the correct and accurate answer by yuji-yamamoto, I discovered that I could also make a symbolic link from the `otherlib` directory directly into the base directory of my own project, and add its name into the `packages` in `stack.yaml`. Specifically, the modified section then reads:

```
packages:
- .
- otherlib-0.9.1
```

..with the directory itself also called `otherlib-0.9.1`.

This solution would work in cases where otherlib is not yet available anywhere outside of the local filesystem.